# Showing if $v+v+v=0$ and $v \neq 0_F$ then the space is above $\Bbb F_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm having difficulty proving the following:

Suppose V is a vector space over $\Bbb F$ and $v\in V$ such that $v \neq 0_F$ and $v+v+v=0$.

I'd like to show  $\forall u \in V$ that $u+u+u=0$.

My intuition suggests that this is only possible if $\Bbb F = \Bbb F_3$ but I'm having trouble composing a rigorous proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $v+v+v=0_V$, which gives you
$$0_V=v+v+v=(1+1+1)v$$
and since $v\neq 0_V$, you get $1+1+1=0_{\mathbb{F}}$ in the field $\mathbb{F}$.

You can use this to prove $u+u+u=0_V$ for all $u\in V$.

However, $\mathbb{F}$ is not necessarily $\mathbb{F}_3$, there are many fields with this property. Examples include $\mathbb{F}_3(t)$, $\mathbb{F}_9$ and many others, although you might not yet know those fields.